# Kotlin Generic declaration-site variance with use-site variance

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
class X<out T> {
  
  // Type parameter T is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'in' position in type X<T>
  fun doSomethingX(x: X<T>) { }
  
}

class Y<in T> {
  
  // Type parameter T is declared as 'in' but occurs in 'out' position in type Y<T>
  fun doSomethingY(y: Y<T>) { }
  
}
```

I understood doSomethingX has x parameter with 'in' position (having parameter with type parameter means 'in' position), therefore, error of class X makes sense.

However, I can't understand why doSomethingY casuses error...

Does anyone know the reason for the error?

I read kotlin docs, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance, but couldn't get enough answers.

---

Added.
Similarly, I found this phenomenon.

```
fun main() {
  X<Number>(1).doSomething(X<Int>(2))
  X<Int>(1).doSomething(X<Number>(2))
}

class X<out|in T>(private val t: T)

fun <R> X<R>.doSomething(x: X<R>) {
  println(this)
  println(x)
}
```

Main function does not have compile error if class X has any declaration-site vairance.
From this phenomenon, I guess the parameter of generic class in declaration-site generic class regards as both 'in' and 'out' position.

But why?! Why Kotlin operates like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the Liskov substitution principle, you are allowed to pass a subtype of a specified type as an argument to the function. Since `Y` has a contravariant `in` generic, any instance of `Y` whose type is a **supertype** of `T` is a *subtype* of `Y<T>`.

When a function consumes a parameter, it can safely consume **subtypes** of it. The parameter is in "in" position.

But if your function tries to "consume" a `Y<T>`, it is trying to consume something whose generic type could be a **supertype** of `T`, which is "out" position.

In other words, subtypes of the function parameter `Y` can wrap supertypes of `T`. If the input `T` can be a supertype, it is in opposition to the direction you can safely cast a function parameter.

Comment: Thanks for answering! :) Howerver, I still can't understand "But if your function tries to "consume" a Y<T>, it is trying to consume something whose generic type could be a supertype of T, which is "out" position."

I understand Y<Number> is a subtype of Y<Int> because Y use 'in' variance annotation, But, why consuming supertype of T means "out" position? we can do nohting in function doSomethingY. for example just print("Hello World")

Comment: Another way to put it. Regardless of whether there are generics at all, a function can accept parameters of the type it specifies, or subtypes of what it specifies. Subtypes of a type that has an `in T` generic are classes with a a generic type that could be a **supertype** of T. But T is `in` for the class so it can only handle `T` and subtypes of `T`. These two behavior requirements are in conflict so it is disallowed. Also, it might help you to try to think through the logic if you use for the function parameter some other class with `in T` such as Comparable instead of using Y.

Comment: The generic type of a contravariant class (a class with an `in` generic type) makes the class less specific as the type itself  gets more specific, and vice versa. For example, `Comparable<Number>` is a subtype of `Comparable<Int>` because `Number` is a supertype of `Int`. Something that can consume any type of number is more specific than one thats only known to be able to consume Ints. This makes `T` behave the opposite of `Y<in T>` in terms of what is more or less specific. So a function for a class with `in T` can consume `T` but not `Y<in T>`.

Comment: Oh, maybe this will make it click. When the function parameter is just T, then T is in “in” position because as T gets more specific, the function parameter is getting more specific (since they are the same thing). But if the function parameter is a `Comparable`, then whatever you specify as the generic type of the Comparable is in “out” position, because as that type gets more specific, the overall type of the parameter is getting **less** specific. So you cannot specify T as that generic type because T is declared as only being allowed in the “in” position in this class Y.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindness!!!!! I guess I understand!! it was very helpful "When the function parameter is just T, then T is in “in” position because as T gets more specific, the function parameter is getting more specific (since they are the same thing)" --> [1] function parameter T allows subtype of T (which means 'in' position) [2] function parameter C<T> allows C<supertype of T> because in variance annotation [3] Here, due to [1] if T of C<T> is really "in" position, C<supertype of T> can not come here. It means C<T> is 'out' position itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just understood the meaning of "out" and "in" is about the output and input of function (parameter or return value). The real meaning of "out" and "in" was "replaceable" in safe type system. Thank you :) Have a nice day~!